# Relative invariants of $P\oplus P^*$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Let $P$ be a $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-module, and assume that the decomposition of $P$ into irreducible submodules is known. By a *relative invariant* of the module $P\oplus P^*$, I mean a homogeneous nonzero element $F$ of the polynomial algebra $S^\bullet(P\oplus P^*)^*\equiv S^\bullet(P\oplus P^*)$, such that the (one-dimensional) span $\langle F\rangle$ is a(n irreducible) submodule.

Since
$$
S^k(P\oplus P^*)=\bigoplus_{i=0}^kS^i(P)\otimes S^{k-i} (P^*)\, ,
$$
I can produce one-dimensional submodules by tensor-multiplying one-dimensional submodules (if any). What I'm really interested in are the **one-dimensional submodules which cannot be expressed as a product** (allow me to call them "prime" - if you know the correct name, I'll be glad to learn it!). For example, if $k$ is even, then
$$
S^{\frac{k}{2}}(P)\otimes S^{\frac{k}{2}} (P^*)=\textrm{End}(S^{\frac{k}{2}}(P))
$$
contains the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $\textrm{id}_{S^{k/2}(P)}$, which is clearly a "prime" submodule.

> **QUESTION:** how to obtain *all* the "prime" one-dimensional submodules of $S^k(P\oplus P^*)$?

I suspect that those generated by $\textrm{id}_{S^{k/2}(P)}$ are the only ones, but I'm absolutely unable to prove it! There should be some well-known trick to deal with this problem, but so far nobody I asked could give any hint.

Comment: Suppose $P$ is the adjoint representation of $SL(V)$. The "prime" submodules of $S^k(P)$ are often called Casimirs. These are non-trivial, and show that "prime" submodules do not only occur in tensor products of submodules that are dual to each other, since $S^k(P)\subset S^k(P\oplus P^\ast)$.

Comment: Let me get straight: $P$ is the Lie algebra ${\frak{sl}}(V)$ of traceless endomorphisms, and $S^k(P)$ is regarded as a subspace of the universal enveloping algebra $U(P)$, right? Then, since a nonzero Casimir commutes with $P$, it is fixed by the action of the Lie group $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ and then it spans an irreducible one-dimensional submodule, did I get it correctly? So far, you have just spotted some one-dimensional irreducible constituents in $S^k(P)$. But your way of understanding "prime" is not - I think - the one I meant in my question.